# Chrome extension development enabled/disabled variable

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am currently trying to make a Chrome extension but I have ran into a problem that I cannot find a fix too.

Okay so basically I have a popup and I made a variable called isEnabled and by default it set to false, but when the user clicks on a button it will change the variable to true and there is some html text at the bottom of the popup which will change depending on what the isEnabled variable is equal to.

But when the user closes/leaves the popup the variable will go back to default.

Here is my popup.html code:

```
<div div class="state">
            <font color="black">Status: </font>
            <font color="red" id="theState">DISABLED</font>
        </div>
        <script src="scripts/popup.js"></script>
```

Here is my Js code:

```
    var statusButton = document.getElementById('status');
var theState = document.getElementById('theState');

//default 
var isEnabled = false;

statusButton.onclick = function () {
    if(isEnabled == false){
        isEnabled = true;
        theState.innerHTML='DISABLED';
    }
    else if(isEnabled == true){
        isEnabled = false;
        theState.innerHTML='INABLED';
    }
};
```

So how do I make the variable not reset if the user closes/leaves the popup or even closes the browser?

Comment: Use a cookie.  There's a bunch of info out there about how to do it.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: The popup and background run in different contexts - look up "message passing" to accomplish this.